# Unexpected behaviour when using grep with lapply

Tags: r

How does R find (grep) "hello" in the first and second elements of the list? When not using a direct function in `lapply`.

```
test_list <- list(c("",""),"",c("hello","goodbye"),c("hello"))
lapply(test_list,grep,"hello")

[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1

[[3]]
[1] 1

[[4]]
[1] 1
```

Typing it using function notation seems to return what one would expect:

```
lapply(test_list, function(x) grep("hello",x))
[[1]]
integer(0)

[[2]]
integer(0)

[[3]]
[1] 1

[[4]]
[1] 1
```

What is the difference between the two that creates the results?

Comment: the first one is `grep(c('',''), 'hello')` not `grep('hello', c('',''))` which is probably what you would think. `test_list` is first passed to grep, then the second argument 'hello', both by position, since you didn't name them: `lapply(test_list,grep, pattern="hello")`

Comment: @rawr sounds like the answer to me. Just a matter of how `lapply` passes args (or more acurately, how `grep` accepts arguments)

Comment: You have to love how similar R functions swap order of their arguments.... endless fun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that:

1. `grep` expects its first argument to be the string to search for (not the string to search within).
2. `lapply` passes each element of the vector/list to iterate over, as the first argument to the supplied function.

Comment: I'm sure brandon knows this, but just forgot for a moment. It happens to all of us.

Comment: Appreciate the vote of confidence, but I scratched my head for a couple minutes like... what did I do?